# Retrieve photos from half booting tablet

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery

Last week I retrieved an Android Tablet (an [Asus Transformer Pad tf300t](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_transformer_pad_tf300t-4596.php)).
Now it does not want to boot-up. To be honest, I don't really care about the tablet itself, but the photos on it.

I can boot in on fast boot I think, and see three icons: RCK, Android and Wipe data.

When you connect the USB cable to it, the computer will recognize the fast boot of the tablet. But you cannot do anything with it.

So how can I get the photos from the tablet :(

/Daan

Comment: Fastboot usually only can *write to*, but not *read from* the device's partitions. RCK most likely stands for the "ReCovery Konsole"; if you're very lucky (rare case here), ADB might recognize it there (or it might offer some backup options). Could you please [edit] your question and include the full name of the device?

Comment: I cannot find it, it does not have a serial number (c8okct032813). But I cannot find the model.... When I press RCK, I get a error..

Comment: Isn't there a name on the cover, or on the box (if you still have it)? Or maybe you've kept the bill? Without some identifier, it's hard to recommend a straight way. I thought e.g. if it is an MTK device, one could use *Flashtool* to extract the partitions and then *TestDisk* to retrieve contents.

Comment: It is an Asus transformer pad tf300t (took some time to find it)

Comment: OK, that seems to rule out the *MTK Flashtool* approach, sorry :(